# Labels not ellipsized in BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I have a layout with `BottomNavigationView` with the attribute `app:labelVisibilityMode` set to `labeled`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Menu has five items:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_navigation"
        android:title="Short" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications_1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_navigation"
        android:title="Short" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_navigation"
        android:title="Longer text123" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications_2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_navigation"
        android:title="Short" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications_3"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_navigation"
        android:title="Short" />

</menu>
```

There is a problem with the third item, with the longer label (`"Longer text123"`) - second word is not ellipsized, but simply not displayed:

[image]

Making the label a little bit shorter causes correct behavior:

[image]

Is there a way to handle longer labels? The best solution would be to ellipsize it and display "Longer text..." when there is no room for the whole text.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and searched a lot. Finally I got a solution to be added in the code. 
Just add the following lines to your code.

```
 BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) navigation.getChildAt(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
        BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
        View activeLabel = item.findViewById(R.id.largeLabel);
        if (activeLabel instanceof TextView) {
            activeLabel.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This solution also helped me to fix issue with barely fitting menu items. They were shown ok when not selected, but were shrinked when selected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/color_c3c3c3"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/color_aaaaaa"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_bottom" />
```

try this